# How can I plot a 3D graph of a given Laplace Transform of a function?

Tags: matlab, laplace-transform

Let's say I have a function called $f(t)$ in time domain as:

$$f(t) = \exp(-3t)\cos(5t)$$

And the Laplace transform of this function call it $F(s)$ becomes:

$$F(s)=\frac{(s + 3)}{(s + 3)^2 + 25}$$

I want to plot the 3D plot of $\lvert F(s)\rvert$ as a surface above the $s$-plane.

I couldn't find any script. I have the version R2014a of MATLAB.
How is this done in MATLAB? Something similar to this plot:

[image]

Comment: Look into meshgrid, there are plenty of examples of 3D plots using MATLAB and this function that should help you

Comment: I couldn't find a single one in hours of search, can you provide me a link if you know where they have an example how they plot Laplace transform above the s plane? Specifically Laplace transform's magnitude above the s plane.

Comment: I do have such an example- I will put it up as an answer for you when I get home later tonight

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/creating-mesh-and-surface-plots.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:.1:10);
s=X+j*Y;
Z= abs((s+3)./((s+3).^2+25));
mesh(X,Y,Z)
```

[image: 3d plot]